# Convergence/divergence of the sum $\sum_{n=2}^\infty 1/ \ln(n!) $

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, logarithms

Is the sum

$$ \sum_{n =2}^{\infty} \frac{1}{\ln n!} $$

convergent or divergent? I have tried different methods and it doesn't work. Perhaps comparing with a divergent series will work? I'm thinking it is divergent.

Comment: $\ln n!\le \ln n^n=n\ln n$.

Comment: actually, i think it converges

Comment: Note that the series $\sum \frac{1}{n\log(n)}$ diverges, for example by the integral test (consider $\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x\log(x)}$ and use a $u=\log(x)$ substitution)

Comment: Why do people answer in the comments?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is clear that
$$n! = 1 \cdot 2 \cdot \dots \cdot n \le n \cdot n \cdot \dots \cdot n = n^n$$
and since $\log$ is increasing, $\ln(n!) \le \ln(n^n) = n \ln n$. Taking the reciprocal, this gives
$$\frac{1}{\ln(n!)} \ge \frac{1}{n \ln n}.$$
But by comparing to the integral
$$\int_2^\infty \frac{dx}{x \ln x} = \int_2^\infty \frac{(\ln x)'}{\ln x} dx = [ \ln(\ln x)]_2^\infty = + \infty,$$
the series $\sum \frac{1}{n \ln n}$ is divergent, thus $\sum \frac{1}{\ln(n!)}$ is divergent too.

Comment: Alternatively you could use the Cauchy condensation tese to $\sum \frac{1}{n \log n}$.

Comment: @Dominik You can write another answer if you wish.